# Can I subtract two variables with two different summation and subscript

Tags: summation, random-variables

Help, I know this may seem basic but I am not sure if I could subtract this:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i^2}}{n} - \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{X_j^2}}{n}$$

Comment: Try small values of $n$ to see how it works. Write out each sum fully.

Comment: Are the two variables refer to the same variable? Or may be one of them is Y not X - Just be sure.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n} - \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2}{n}
= \frac{X_1^2 + \dots + X_n^2 - X_1^2 - \dots - X_n^2}{n}
= \frac{(X_1^2 - X_1^2) + \dots + (X_n^2 - X_n^2)}{n}
= 0
$$

Comment: **** It would help if the person who downvotes an answer to suggest a correction or state why the answer is not correct. ***

Comment: I’m not the downvoter, but I do find this answer unhelpful. All it does it confirm the subtraction can indeed be done in this case without making any effort to articulate why. It would have nice if you’d made some mention of ‘dummy variables’ and how they work.

Comment: I think its pretty self explanatory. All I do is expand out the summation then group the terms which are the same.

Comment: I’ll upvote. Answer is very clear.